# javascript click being called twice and more

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im suspecting something weird happens here;

```
$('#botonAñadir').fadeOut(500, function (e) {
    $('#botonEditar').fadeIn(500).on('click', function (e) {
         console.log(DEBUG + 'en el click del boton');
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();   
         localStorage.removeItem(contacto);
         that.nuevoContacto();
         $(this).fadeOut(500, function () {
             $('#botonAñadir').fadeIn();
         });
    });
});
```

when i click on #botonAñadir the first time works as expected but the second time you click it call twice that.nuevoContacto(), and so on so the third time calls it 3 times, etc.

Am I following any anti-pattern or such? I cant get it why it behaves like so.

Is there a problem combining fades with on?

EDIT.

I made it like below, even i know it looks ugly at this hour my brain is fryied;

```
$('#botonAñadir').fadeOut(500, function (e) {
    $('#botonEditar').fadeIn(500);
 });  

 $('#botonEditar').on('click', function (e) {
     console.log(DEBUG + 'en el click del boton');
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();   
     localStorage.removeItem(contacto);
     that.nuevoContacto();
     $(this).fadeOut(500, function () {
           $('#botonAñadir').fadeIn();
           $('#botonEditar').off('click');
     });
});
```

Comment: That's because you're repeatedly adding the event handler, every single time.

Comment: How do you call the code that you've shown?

Comment: To elaborate on Niet's find: Each time you call "<JQuery selection>.on()", you're creating an event handler. I think you'd want to reorganize your code so it's only being called once.

Comment: its quite big code, but yes i will try to take it out from there and test it

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol already mentioned, there is no need to rebind this way unless you are doing something like removing and re-adding an element with the same ID.

Comment: I solved it calling .off at the end of the on, because i need to have it there due to contacto var. not sure if its ideal but works. thanks to all to point me out the issue, i was blind

Comment: that was a quick fix. Once I finish it I will refactor the entire object, taking all your comments in consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding the onClick event handler every time your element fades in.

Try binding the event handler outside the the fade effect, or use .off('click')  before binding the handler again:

```
$('#botonEditar').fadeIn(500).off('click').on('click', function (e) {...
```

Comment: Using this solution however would only be wise if you'd want to change what happens when you click on the element. Re-assigning the same event handler every time would be a waste of resources.

Answer (score 1):

They way you have this written, the `on('click'...` portion is adding another click handler every time the fade out function is executed...

Try using `.once()` or rewriting to put the `on()` at the beginning...

```
 $('#botonEditar').fadeIn(500).once('click', function (e) {
```